# CSS snap box like facebook timeline or about.com

Tags: css, cross-browser

Its possible to creating snap box, like facebook timeline or about.com without javascript/jquery?. And its crossbrowser.

I mean irregular box.

Facebook: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i/472778-12222011104910am.png

About.com:
http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i/974882-12222011104727am.png

Comment: A link or screenshot of the "snapping box" would be usefull because very little people will know what you mean.

Comment: I can't see any commonalities between Timeline and About.com, so I haven't been able to divine what a 'snap box' is. Screenshots?

Comment: Hmmm ... from the screenshots you posted i can only conclude that your snapboxes are plain images or arrows pointing nowhere ...

Comment: In future, please use the image upload/linking functionality provided in the editor. The site you've linked to is no longer hosting the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing cross-browser that will accomplish "vertically floated" boxes without using some Javascript to simulate it.

If you decide jQuery is okay, look at [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: wow :) thanks, I need only css :) its okay, if there is jquery solution. maybe I'll using <noscript> tag or modernizr js.